# Nano: can the escape key be mapped?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nano

I've been playing with the keyboard mapping in the .nanorc file some today, and you can map the F keys like...`bind F3 cancel all`, however, i haven't had any luck with trying find how nano recognizes the escape key. I've already tried `Esc`, `esc`, nano keeps giving me an error message. Is there a way to bind/map the escape key in the corner of your keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it.

The keys which could be mapped are described here:
https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Rebinding-Keys

It also has a statement:

> Rebinding ^[ (Esc) is not possible, because its keycode is the starter byte of Meta keystrokes and escape sequences.